# System freezes in Opera browser and Zoom

Tags: drivers, 22.04, amd-graphics, opera

I had a problem with Opera browser freezing in the following conditions:

- Full screen videos freeze Opera and show a "force quit or wait" warning.
- The browser freezes when I open a drop-down menu.

I solved this problem in Opera by cancelling hardware acceleration.

But that didn't solve the problem in general.

I have a similar problem with Zoom software. Every time I click on a menu it freezes and I have to force quit. I'm guessing whatever is the problem is the same for all software.

Is there a solution to this?

This is a laptop with a AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics

$free
total        used     free       shared   buff/cache   available
Mem:        14135860  3096632   3726048   182672     7313180    10535724
Swap:        2097148     1388      2095760

Comment: If there's a UEFI update already released make sure to apply it.

Comment: How much RAM & swap do you have? `free` will tell you. Read `man free mkswap swapon; man -a fstab`. You should have swap the same size as RAM to support suspend/hibernate.

Comment: total             used        free              shared      buff/cache   available
Mem:        14135860     3096632     3726048      182672     7313180    10535724
Swap:        2097148        1388         2095760